# Access parent select2 control element from iframe and set its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-select2

I have a base document that loads like http://localhost/index.php?action=test.  This document has a button that opens a div with an iframe which loads another document from the same domain http://localhost/index.php?action=search.  Now I have the results and on click of a link in the iframe, I need to access a field (which is a select2 control) in the parent and set the value.

The generated html looks like this:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="fldlabel">
   <div><label for="header[CTRYID]">Country</label></div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input tabindex="-1" id="header-CTRYID" data-label="Country" name="header[CTRYID]" class="ajaxselect srchtarget-CTRYID validate select2-offscreen" data-validate="required" value="" data-placeholder="Select Country" type="text">
   <span class="hdricon">
     <a href="CTRYID-search" data-source="index.php?action=search&amp;source=CTRYID" class="srchbutton"><img class="imgicon" src="/images/icons/search.ico" alt="Search Country"></a>
   </span>
   <div class="searchpanel" id="CTRYID-search" style="">
    <div class="frametitle">Search Country </div>
     <div class="srchbody">
       <iframe src="index.php?action=search&amp;source=CTRYID" class="srchframe">
        #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head></head>
         <body>
          <div id="container">
           <div id="content" style="overflow: hidden;" tabindex="5000">
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=search&source=CTRYID" name="country">
             <div id="searchselect" class="srchrslt">
              <div class="frametitle">Search Results</div>
               <table border="1" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr class="gridrow searchrow" data-search="IN|India" data-target="CTRYID">
                   <td>IN</td>
                   <td>India</td>
                   <td>IND</td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
             </div>
           </form>
         </div>
       </iframe>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Below is the jquery code that I've been trying.

```
$('.searchrow').click(function (e) {
    alert($('#srchtarget-CTRYID',window.parent.document).attr('id'));
    e.preventDefault();
    var srchdata = $(this).data('search').split("|");
    var srchval = JSON.stringify({"id":srchdata[0],"text":srchdata[0]+"|"+srchdata[1]});
    var target = "srchtarget-" + $(this).data('target');
    $(target,window.document).select2().select2('val',srchval);
    $(this).parent().find('.searchpanel').hide();
  //        $(this).parents().find(target).val(srchval);
});
```

I'm getting the values from php, only my jquery does not work. I have tried `window.parent`, `window.parent.document`, `window.top.document` (as you can see from the code above) but none of those seem to work.  Any property that I access outside the iframe results as undefined (the alert in the above code).

**UPDATE:**

After playing around, I get the value with `window.parent.document` but I still could not get the value into the select2 control.  My current code looks like below:

```
$('.searchrow').click(function (e) {
    var srchdata = $(this).data('search').split("|");
    var srchval = [];
    srchval.push({"id": srchdata[0], "text": srchdata[0] + "|" + srchdata[1]});
    var target = ".srchtarget-" + $(this).data('target');
    var parentctrl = window.parent.document;
    $(target,parentctrl).select2('data',srchval);
    $(this).closest('.searchpanel').hide();
    $('.searchpanel', parentctrl).hide();
});
```

I have checked the parent target element (unique class name in my case) is correctly populated in the variable and the value exists in the data variable (as JSON object).

**UPDATE 2:**

I have replaced the unique class with the id of the parent element (since select2 was replicating the class from the parent into the select2 control) so I get a real unique id for the parent.  However, the result is the same.  I still don't get to populate the results in the control.  My updated target is as below and I get my target id is correctly populated:

```
    var target = "#" + $(this).data('target');
```

I've searched, read and tried all solutions that came up in SO and in internet but none worked. Can anyone help?

Comment: You do realize that anything inside `<iframe></iframe>` tags is only shown if the browser does not support Javascript (or has it turned off), right?

Comment: Lol! @Sverri, the code pasted above is from Firebug source, not from my html page.  I patched both the main page code and iframe code here to show the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to v4 and the below code 'kinda' works for pushing the values (but the select2 control is duplicated with the option. possibly a bug in v4).

```
$('.searchrow').click(function (e) {
  var srchdata = $(this).data('search').split("|");
  var target = ".srchtarget-" + $(this).data('target');
  var targetoption = target + " option[value='" + srchdata[0] + "']";
  var parentctrl = window.parent.document;
  $(targetoption,parentctrl).attr("selected","selected");
  $(target,parentctrl).select2();
});
```